# OSM XML: Should I generate contact:phone or phone?

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, point-of-interest

I am generating [OSM XML](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) data for all POIs of [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org), the collaborative travel guide.

When I want to express a phone number, should I generate `contact:phone` or `phone`?

Both mean the same thing. According to a 2012 note on [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3acontact%3aphone), the only difference is that `contact:phone` is newer but `phone` is more popular.

Which one should I use, that so my data is readable by most 2013 apps?

Comment: What is the purpose of the phone number? Any reason to not generate both?

Comment: Purpose example: In a map navigation app like AndOsm, a traveller would see Wikivoyage restaurants on the map, tap on one to see the phone number, and a second tap allows her to call the restaurant in order to make a reservation. Generating both is technically feasible indeed (if not forbidden by the XML schema, I haven't checked), the only drawback being a more heavy file (and the file is already quite heavy).

Comment: Please keep in mind, that data imports are always an difficult topic in the OSM community:  
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Automated_Edits  
Please don't add bulkdata without prior discussion with the (local!) communities and quality checks.

Comment: ＠Mapper: The data will not be added to OSM. It will be used as an extra layer in navigation apps. Apps like OsmAnd allow users to download and use custom OSM XML files to complement OSM maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate both of course, this is not forbidden. There are several things in OSM that can be expressed with more than one tag, simply because [anybody is allowed to propose or create new tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Any_tags_you_like). Likewise, data consumers always must keep that in mind and not just process the most popular tag.

If you want to use only one of the two tags then you might want to stick to the more popular one. [phone](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/phone) is clearly more popular than [contact:phone](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/contact%3aphone). Using the most popular one should ensure that most of the data consumers are able to recognize it. But if you are generating this OSM XML file just for yourself then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks! Duplicating information frustrates me a bit. By the way, the file will be distributed widely.

Comment: OSM has a highly social aspect, so you need to understand that the format itself isn't tuned for a special purpose but allowing everybody to contribute, which is very important :)